# nil or empty for @page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I try to use gem ckeditor. I install the gem by doc. I need to add the code to view:

```
<% form_for @page do |form| %>
  <%= form.cktext_area :notes, class: 'someclass', ckeditor: { language: 'uk'} %>
  <%= form.cktext_area :content, value: 'Default value', id: 'sometext' %>
  <%= cktext_area :page, :info, cols: 40, ckeditor: { uiColor: '#AADC6E', toolbar: 'mini' } %>

 <% end %>
```

I get the error:

`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty.`
I understand the gem have page controller and I need to do '@page = Page.new', but my app don't contain page controller.
How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you placing this form? You will need to set the instance variable somewhere. `@page` is simply an example in the Docs. Additionally, **User be Warned** that gem has not been updated in 3 years. It claims CKeditor 4 which reached EOL in June 2023 and claims Rails 5.x, 4.2.x integration. Rails 5.2 reached end of life in June of 2022. Both will likely have security vulnerabilities and incompatibilities that will not be addressed going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the example given in the ckeditor README so it matches what you need for your app. You would add the `form.cktext_area` field to the form view for whatever model and field you want to add the editor for.